# How to see if string list of rgb match regex pattern?

Tags: python, regex

for security reasons I'd like to check if a string `list` of `rgb` is valid using regex.

Here's what the string list could look like : `'[255, 248, 234], [129, 85, 2], [2, 5, 55]'`, rgb must be in array, and well separated from each other with a coma, same for array separation with a coma, each value can contain from 1 to 3 values which should be numbers.

I know that you can check patterns but I have no idea on how to check on this specific regex

```
import re
pattern = re.compile("^[^0-9.]+$") #doesn't seem to be the good regex for what I'm trying
pattern.match(string)
```

Any solution ?

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/3y49Jj/1, `^\[\d+(?:,\s*\d+){2}](?:,\s*\[\d+(?:,\s*\d+){2}]){2}$`

Comment: @anubhava it could be anything as long it's like rgb, example : `'[5, 8, 4], [29, 85, 92], [255, 255, 255]'`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Maybe ^\[\d+(?:,\s*\d+){2}](?:,\s*\[\d+(?:,\s*\d+){2}])*$  - for unlimited number of [n,n,n] ?

Comment: Must be three [] groups there?

Comment: @Gangnus 3 values in the list, but could be as many list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
from ast import literal_eval

inp = '[255, 248, 264], [129, 85, 2], [2, 5, 55]'
inp2 = '[5, 8, 4], [29, 85, 92], [255, 255, 255]'

def is_valid_rgb(inp):
    evalinp = literal_eval(inp)
    for rgb in evalinp:
        for c in rgb:
            if c < 0 or c > 255
                return False
    return True

print is_valid_rgb(inp) #False
print is_valid_rgb(inp2) #True
```

Of course, at this point might as well just do a check that `c <= 255 and c >= 0` instead of using a regex. The problem with just using `\d` is that it doesn't catch numbers outside of the range as invalid values.

Comment: interesting, what does literal_eval do ?

Comment: It evaluates a string as if it were python code. https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval. So basically it converts your string into a tuple (of any length) of int lists, and then look at each value to make sure it's within the correct range. I used a regex for that check, but an integer comparison would be better.

Comment: Perfect for my case !

Comment: Too many errors. Allows 00, 000, 01,02,..., not allowing 001... 099. And the whole is code, not regex. That means, it is much more slow.

Comment: @gangnus 000 is a valid color, and using int comparison as I mentioned allows 001..099. Your regex doesn't match those. Any reasonable rbg tool recognizes the equivalence of 000 and 0, along with, say, 9, 09, and 009. OP didn't give the exact spec, so it's silly to make it up for him. Using a regex might be faster, but that's a different question.

Comment: You are not answering my message, but something else. Your regex is simply full of errors. Repair it, if you can. It is taking 999, for example. Nonsense. If you allow 000 (And I have NOTHING against it), for god's sake, why do you not allow 001?

Comment: Not only is it not taking 999 (I have no idea where you got that from, or why you're criticizing something you clearly haven't tested), but I said in my answer that by using literal_eval he or she might as well ignore a regex altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Any number of [num, num, num], while every num is arbitrary number 0-255.

```
^\[(?:\d|[1-9][0-9]|1\d{2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])(?:,\s*(?:\d|[1-9][0-9]|1\d{2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}](?:,\s*\[(?:\d|[1-9][0-9]|1\d{2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])(?:,\s*(?:\d|[1-9][0-9]|1\d{2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}])*$
```

[test cases](https://regex101.com/r/rAJLc0/4)